# Visual Studio is compiling older versions. Cannot find or open PDB file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

c++ works fine, then it gets to the point where it won't register any change I made to my program even if its a simple change in an output statement.

I changed everything back to how it originally was and it still won't build a new solution without giving me a "cannot find or open PDB file"

I took these two screen shots showing what happens. I can "run without debugging", but if I try debugging I get an error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyOQM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcJ6N.png

If I copy all my new code into a new project, it works but then after a couple runs it stops compiling anything new that I add.

Comment: there is a .pdb being created in the debug directory. Should I run that as admin or visual studio. I ran visual studio as admin but still getting same problem

Comment: You do realize that your first screen shot shows a BUILD FAILED, do you?

Comment: Haha yeah, i changed it back to the exact same build as the original one and it still failed. What I have been doing is copying my entire code into a new project and then running and it works then. even when it fails to complile, i copy it exactly as it is into a new project and then it works.

Comment: Building and running for debugging are two differents things. Show us the error message from the BUILD.

Comment: This is what happens when I build it, like I said though, this exact programs runs when i just copy it into a new project without changing anything. http://i.imgur.com/smOEWIp.png

Answer (score 1):

The build fails because a previous instance of the process is still running.

Check Task Manager and KILL all the old EXEs running.

That explains why all is fine when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is not building correctly, so what is probably happening is that Visual studio is running the last version that built correctly and you can't debug that because the code that you have is different then what was used to make that build.

Fix your error and once your project builds without an error then try again and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Like I said above, the code works perfectly when I copy it all and paste it into a new project without changing anything. I have had it a couple times where I get that build error and have to continute coding in a new project to fix it.  i.imgur.com/smOEWIp.png Although I cant do this long term